# How do the numbers on the pH scale compare?

Tags: ph

How do the numbers on the pH scale compare?
Example – is a pH of 4 twice as strong as a pH of 2? Remember the pH scale is not linear! Also, "is 4 twice of 2" isn't my question. I just want to know the way the numbers compare to each other.

Comment: They don't. There is no such thing as "twice as strong" among acids.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH

Comment: Ever heard about logarithms?

Comment: Perhaps it's better for you to ask your own question in your own words, instead of (what seems to be) copy-pasting somebody else's question here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is something that is typically taught in schools the minute the pH scale is introduced.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{pH} = -\mathrm{log}[\mathrm{H}^+]$

i.e. the pH stands for the negative log (base 10) of the concentration of H$^+$.

this means in a solution of HCl (0.1 mol dm$^{-3}$ ) where the HCl is fully dissociated, i.e. $\ce{HCl -> H+ + Cl-}$ the concentration of H$^+$ is 0.1 mol dm$^{-3}$, so $\mathrm{pH} = -\mathrm{log}(0.1) = 1$

if the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ is 10 times greater, i.e. 1 mol dm$^{-3}$, so $\mathrm{pH} = -\mathrm{log}(1) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

The pH scale tells you how acid is a solution, or more formally the concentration of hydronium ion ($\ce{H3O+}$) you have in the solution. Remember that

$pH = - \log([\ce{H3O+}])$

therefore the concentration of $[\ce{H3O+}]$ in a solution with $pH = 4$ will be two orders of magnitude lower than the one with $pH = 2$.

If you do the $Antilog$ of -2 and -4 you will have $\pu{1E-2}$ and $\pu{1E-4}$ respectively.

So the higher the pH the less concentration of $[\ce{H3O+}]$ and less acid (or more alkaline).

Comment: For future reference, you may find https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88 and https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/ helpful for formatting questions and answers on ChemSE (and, partially, LaTeX, too).

Comment: Oh, and in addition to @Buttonwood, don't abuse MathJax for emphasizing text. Use `*italic*` for *italic* and `**bold**` for **bold**.

Answer (score 1):

The pH is a measure of:
 $$\mathrm{pH} = -\mathrm{log}[\mathrm{H}^+]$$
It's a [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), for being more exactly it's a common logarithm (his base is `10`).
In other worlds, this means that each pH is 10 times less "powerful" or acid that the last (it's one order of magnitude lesser).

For example:

- **$\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm{4}$ is 10 times more acid than $\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm{5}$**, or it's one order of magnitude (`x10` times) higher.

It can be some strange to think, but, **higher numbers are not more acids, it's the opposite, higher numbers are less acids and lower numbers are more acids**.

I hope this could help.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: Base 10 logs are called "common logs". Base $e$ logs are the "natural logs".

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Ups, sorry, I'll fix that.

Comment: And I shall remove my downvote :)